# Magento error log filled with errors from Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework, syntax-error, magento-1.8

I've been developing a Magento site for a few weeks now and on the most part it has been going according to plan. However, over the last week I have been head over heels in errors and little things not working and it's really starting to (de)bug me.

I have put all the error logging I can find on Magento to try and find the source of these problems and most of them are pointing me to one file in particular which is oddly enough one of the core Magento files.

So I have uploaded my error log and the file in question to pastebin in the hope that one of your kind overflowers can assist me a little :)

system.log from var/log/: http://pastebin.com/jz8mW51Y

File.php from lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php: http://pastebin.com/GiBrLYnY

I am running Magento 1.8.1 via Turnkey Linux on AWS as well if that is of any help.

Answer (score 0):

The `$_options` property of the `Zend_Cache_Backend_File` class you posted at pastebin.com uses the wrong characters `‘` and `’` to delimit its keys instead of using proper single quotes `'`.

Replace all `‘` and `’` against `'` and the `Notice: Use of undefined constant` will be gone.